# Can v.simpleRecord be used to get data from managed package field?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package

I want to be able to pass the field value of my managed package to the lightning component which then passes it onto the canvas app through parameters. Is there a way to pass managed package field using v.simplerecord? 
I am able to pass v.simpleRecord.Name etc.but when trying to pass v.namespaceofpackage__field__c, the component fails. How to resolve this? and how to succesfully pass managed package field value?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean `v.simplerecord.namespaceofpackage__field__c`, right? Or is this just a simple typo?

Comment: Better you paste code snippet...i've never seen any issue using managed fields in component..